# Unable to install hunspell on windows 10

Tags: python, hunspell

i am unable to install hunspell on windows 10
whenever i try to install it using pip it throws the following error.

```
  Building wheel for hunspell (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 
  Complete output (12 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  building 'hunspell' extension
  creating build
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual 

  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for hunspell
  Running setup.py clean for hunspell
Failed to build hunspell
Installing collected packages: hunspell
    Running setup.py install for hunspell ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tried this ?

```
pip install CyHunspell
```

See https://github.com/OpenGov/cython_hunspell.

Comment: ```self.hs = hunspell.HunSpell('/usr/share/hunspell/en_US.dic','/usr/share/hunspell/en_US.aff')
AttributeError: module 'hunspell' has no attribute 'HunSpell'```    Pyhunspell has this attribute but Cyhunspell does'nt. any solution for this?